# how to recognize if git hook script is really run as a hook

Tags: git

The Opensmalltalk project has some git hooks (post-checkout, post-commit, post-merge) that did check if the scripts were really ran as hook with this (bash) test:

```
is_run_as_hook() {
    test -n "$GIT_DIR"
}
```

This was probably too clever a hack: run the same script for installing the hook than for running the hook, see

https://github.com/OpenSmalltalk/opensmalltalk-vm/blob/623dee2b6589723173af8b10d73485a23202c44f/scripts/updateSCCSVersions

It used to work up to git 2.18...
But GIT_DIR is no longer set, and as discussed in git mailing list, the fact that GIT_DIR was set was an un-intentional side-effect...
https://public-inbox.org/git/20180826004150.GA31168@sigill.intra.peff.net/t/

Thus my question: is there another way to recognize being ran as hook, or should we rather change the whole logic?

Comment: The only way I can think of is to verify that `$basename $0` is `.git/hooks`. And never run hooks as scripts from `.git/hooks`. Fragile solution, but I suspect any solution will be fragile.

Comment: @phd I guess you meant `$dirname $0`. It sounds good.

Comment: Yes, `dirname`, sorry.

Comment: You can set `GIT_DIR` yourself using `GIT_DIR="$(git rev-parse --git-dir)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to verify that `dirname $0` is `.git/hooks`. And never run hooks as scripts from `.git/hooks`. Fragile solution, but I suspect any solution will be fragile.